# Install Freetds v1 - Centos 6.10 - Connect to MSSQL 2016

Tags: sql-server, centos6, freetds

I have to connect to a MSSQL database server recently upgraded to 2016 version.

I've read that i need freetds version 1.0 at minimum.(https://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm)

On the epel repository of Centos 6.10 i can find only freetds 0.91.

How i can install FreeTDS version 1 on Centos 6.10 ?

Answer (score 0):

You may not **need** FreeTDS 1.0+. With version 0.91, you can still connect by explicitly passing the `TDS_Version`. For example, from Python:

```
import pyodbc

con = pyodbc.connect(
    r"DRIVER={FreeTDS};"
    r"SERVER=sql.mydomain.com;"
    r"PORT=1433;"
    r"DATABASE=my_database;"
    f"UID=sql_username;"
    f"PWD=sql_password;"
    r"TDS_Version=7.2;"
)

cursor = con.cursor;

cursor.execute("SELECT 'this' AS that")

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

With FreeTDS 0.91, the highest `TDS_Version` you can use is `7.2`, which will support all features of SQL Server up to SQL Server 2005. As long as you are not using `DATE`, `TIME` or `DATETIME2` fields, you will likely be able to do what you need. Give it a whirl?

If that doesn't suffice, to support FreeTDS version `7.3` or `7.4`, you will need to compiled from the source code: https://www.freetds.org/userguide/config.htm